# How to center @gorhom/bottom-sheet with not 100% width?

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

I am using https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/ library and I do not want the BottomSheet to take full width of the screen. So I limit it as

```
<BottomSheet snapPoints={snapPoints} style={{width: '80%'}}>
      ...
</BottomSheet>
```

and try to center it as `justifyContent: 'center'` in View wrapping the BottomSheet. However, it does not work as expected.

[image]

**So the question is:** how do I reduce the width of the BottomSheet and center it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a quick workaround:

```
import {Dimensions, ...} from "react-native";

...

<BottomSheet
  snapPoints={snapPoints}
  style={{marginHorizontal: Dimensions.get("screen").width*0.1}}
>
  ...
</BottomSheet>
```

What it does: It calculates the margin to both sides (right and left): There should be 10% margin to each side (in total a width of 80%).

Hope that helps! :)